# Define behavior of calling join with self thread-id

Tags: c, multithreading

What will be the behavior of following C statement:
pthread_join(pthread_self(), NULL);

Does it mean that the thread will not be able to join any other thread?

Answer (score 1):

It produces undefined behaviour:

*The behavior is undefined if the value specified by the thread argument to pthread_join() refers to the calling thread*

Where thread argument is the first argument, and calling thread this case is pthread_self():

```
                             v
int pthread_join(pthread_t thread, void **value_ptr);
```

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_join.html